# get an array index value inside a JSON response ionic

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have this function this API JSON response ([Github API](https://api.github.com/repositories))

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "grit",
    "full_name": "mojombo/grit",
    "owner": {
      "login": "mojombo",
      "id": 1,
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/1?v=3",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/mojombo",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/mojombo/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "private": false,
    "html_url": "https://github.com/mojombo/grit",
    "description": "**Grit is no longer maintained. Check out libgit2/rugged.** Grit gives you object oriented read/write access to Git repositories via Ruby.",
    "fork": false,
...

    }
]
```

In this function, I want to pass the owner.login element to my function gotoDetails. Is there any simple way to do that?  I tried `repo.owner.login` and `repo.owner['login']`.

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-card *ngFor="let repo of repos" (click)="goToDetails(repo.name, repo.owner['login'])">
      <ion-card-header>
        {{ repo.name }}
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content>
        {{ repo.description }}
      </ion-card-content>
      <ion-icon name="arrow-forward" item-right></ion-icon>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Repos model:

```
import { User } from '../models/users';

export interface Repos {
    name: string,
    full_name: string,
    owner: User, 
    private: boolean,
    html_url: string,
    description: string,
    fork: boolean,
    url: string
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the relation between the title and the question. Regarding your issue maybe try the {{ repo | json }} to debug it

Comment: Use `goToDetails(repo)` an then `console.log(repo)`, see what you got.